# Migrate from one vCenter server to a new one

Tags: migration, vmware-vsphere

We are about to setup a new and more powerful vCenter server for our VMware environment.

It is going to run vCenter 5.0 along with a couple of other things.

However, I want to make the migration as smooth as possible - and how do I do that with our current vCenter?

Should I set it up so they work together in some way, and then just remove the old one?

Any ideas? What is best practice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just snap the current one, backup the databases and follow the regular upgrade instructions from their site, ts easy, if you run into problems just restore.

Comment: Do you have any links to those upgrade instructions?

Comment: REALLY? come on you can do better than that - it took me less than 20 seconds to get to this; http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.vcenterhost.doc_50%2FGUID-3B5AF2B1-C534-4426-B97A-D14019A8010F.html